# How to find the name of the current function at runtime?

Tags: c++, function, assert

After years of using the big ugly MFC ASSERT macro, I have finally decided to ditch it and create the ultimate ASSERT macro.

I am fine with getting the file and line number, and even the expression that failed. I can display a messagebox with these in, and Abort/Retry/Cancel buttons.

And when I press Retry the VS debugger jumps to the line containing the ASSERT call (as opposed to the disassembly somewhere like some other ASSERT functions). So it's all pretty much working.

But what would be really cool would be to *display the name of the function that failed*.

Then I can decide whether to debug it without trying to guess what function it's in from the filename.

e.g. if I have the following function:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
   ASSERT(lpCreateStruct->cx > 0);
   ...
}
```

Then when the ASSERT fires, the messagebox would show something like:

```
Function = CMainFrame::OnCreate
```

**So, what's the simplest way of finding out the current function name, at runtime?**

*It should not use MFC or the .NET framework, even though I do use both of these.

It should be as portable as possible.*

Comment: If you have access to the John Robbins' [Debugging Applications for Microsoft® .NET and Microsoft Windows®](http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-Applications-Microsoft®-Microsoft-Pro-Developer/dp/0735615365/ref=sr_1_16/175-5814253-7853112?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1237928779&sr=8-16) you should definitely look at the assertions from BugSlayerUtil library on the supplied CD. They are Windows-specific, but really ultimate.

Comment: I had a look at http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid3653A5E08C30DB8B7551729FBED0BC3D51B19AD8.aspx but it didn't seem to show the function name. Therefor I think my version is more ultimate than his :D

Comment: It shows stacktrace. Stacktrace contains function names, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. Hmmmmmmm could be useful, but wouldn't that make your lovely messagebox quite unreadable? Point taken though. Maybe in v2 of my macro ;)

Comment: For some reason link to the book is not visible in the answer, here it is: http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-Applications-Microsoft%C2%AE-Microsoft-Pro-Developer/dp/0735615365/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your macro can contain the `__FUNCTION__` macro.
Make no mistake, the function name **will be** inserted into the expanded code at **compile time**, but it will be the correct function name for each call to your macro. So it "seems like" it happens in run-time ;)

e.g.

```
#define THROW_IF(val) if (val) throw "error in " __FUNCTION__

int foo()
{
    int a = 0;
    THROW_IF(a > 0); // will throw "error in foo()"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `__FUNCTION__` is not standard.  `__func__` *is* standard, but it is not a string literal; it acts like a variable, so you can't concatenate it easily.

Comment: right. but luckily the OP is using MFC and so cross-platformness is probably not a problem.

Comment: I mentioned it because OP asked for portability.

Comment: Unfortunately, __func__ is not part of Standard C++.

Comment: __FUNCTION__ is the winner, and it works brilliantly. It even tells you the namespace. I don't require true cross-platformness but only some of the projects in my solution use MFC, so the macro has to work without MFC (that's what I meant by "as portable as possible"). Thanks to all who contributed!

Comment: Oh right, `__func__` is specified C99 but not (yet) in C++.  Sigh...  I guess `__FUNCTION__` is the winner, then.

Comment: There's also `__FUNCSIG__` (again, VC++ specific) - this one includes the full signature of function, not just its name, and is handy to distinguish overloaded functions.

Comment: As per [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), neither `__FUNCTION__` or `__func__` are macros.

Answer (score 28):

The C++ preprocessor macro `__FUNCTION__` gives the name of the function.

Note that if you use this, it's not *really* getting the filename, line number, or function name at runtime. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor, and compiled in.

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>

void function1()
{
        std::cout << "my function name is: " << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

int main()
{
        std::cout << "my function name is: " << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        function1();
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
my function name is: main
my function name is: function1
```

Comment: __FUNCTION__ is not part of the C++ language standard (I didn't downvote yoou for this, but I guess someone else did)

Comment: good point, I think I misread something.
according to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html,
__func__ is part of the C99 standard (although not necessarily everything supports it). __FUNCTION__ is not, although if the big compliers (MSDN/GCC) support it, it's effectively portable.

Comment: Note that __func__ is not part of C++ either.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. And I'll let you off for saying __FUNCTION__ is portable. It's portable enough for me anyway :)

Comment: Thanks. :) I think I realize my mistake, too. C99 is a C standard, not C++.

Comment: @YenTheFirst - Given that you realized you posted incorrect info, would you consider fixing the answer instead of just leaving a comment?

Answer (score 19):

There's no standard solution. However, [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html#boost_current_function) is portable for all practical purposes.  The header does not not depend on any of the other Boost headers, so can be used standalone if the overhead of the whole library is unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use Boost (yet) but at least I know there's a substitute for __FUNCTION__ if I ever have the need to port it.

Comment: The header for {{BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION}} is standalone. You can just download it and put it in your codebase without anything else from Boost.

Answer (score 11):

`__FUNCTION__` or `__FUNC__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

Answer (score 10):

In GCC you can use the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro.
Microsoft also have an equivalent `__func__` macro although I don't have that available to try.

e.g. to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` putting something like this at the beginning of your functions and you'll get a complete trace

```
void foo(char* bar){
  cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl
}
```

which will output

```
void foo(char* bar)
```

You also have the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros available under all standard c/c++ compilers if you want to output even more information.

In practice I have a special debugging class which I use instead of cout.  By defining appropriate environment variables I can get a full program trace.  You could do something similar.  These macros are incredibly handy and it's really great to be able to turn on selective debugging like this in the field.

EDIT: apparently `__func__` is part of the standard? didn't know that.  Unfortunately, it only gives the function name and not the parameters as well.  I do like gcc's `__PRETTY_FUNC__` but it's not portable to other compilers.

GCC also supports `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: For Microsoft, `__FUNCSIG__` works similarly to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. (Neither they nor `__func__` are macros, for the record.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`__FUNCTION__` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx) which at compile time will be expanded to the name of the function.

Here's an example of how to use it in an assert macro.

```
#define ASSERT(cond) \
    do { if (!(cond)) \
    MessageBoxFunction("Failed: %s in Function %s", #cond, __FUNCTION__);\
    } while(0)

void MessageBoxFunction(const char* const msg,  ...)
{
    char szAssertMsg[2048];

    // format args
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, msg);
    vsprintf(szAssertMsg, msg, vargs);
    va_end(vargs);

    ::MessageBoxA(NULL, szAssertMsg, "Failed Assertion", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: @demoncodemonkey: Trevor asks a very question. Why shouldn't Andrew use a variadic function here?

Answer (score 4):

**C++20 `std::source_location::function_name`**

No macros are needed now that we have proper standardization:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <source_location>

void log(std::string_view message,
         const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current()
) {
    std::cout << "info:"
              << location.file_name() << ":"
              << location.line() << ":"
              << location.function_name() << " "
              << message << '\n';
}

int f(int i) {
    log("Hello world!"); // Line 16
    return i + 1;
}

int f(double i) {
    log("Hello world!"); // Line 21
    return i + 1.0;
}

int main() {
    f(1);
    f(1.0);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o source_location.out source_location.cpp
./source_location.out
```

Output:

```
info:source_location.cpp:16:int f(int) Hello world!
info:source_location.cpp:21:int f(double) Hello world!
```

so note how the call preserves caller information, so we see the desired `main` call location instead of `log`.

I have covered the relevant standards in a bit more detail at: [What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func/31163837#31163837)

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, GCC 11.3.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily use **func**.
it will take back you current function name at runtime which raised the exception.

usage:

```
cout << __func__ << ": " << e.what();
```