# What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

What's the difference between `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__`, and where are they documented? How do I decide which one to use?

Answer (score 363, accepted):

`__func__` is an implicitly declared identifier that expands to a character array variable containing the function name when it is used inside of a function.  It was added to C in C99.  From [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) §6.4.2.2/1:

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.  This name is the unadorned name of the function.

Note that it is not a macro and it has no special meaning during preprocessing.

`__func__` was added to C++ in C++11, where it is specified as containing "an implementation-deﬁned string" (C++11 §8.4.1[dcl.fct.def.general]/8), which is not quite as useful as the specification in C. (The original proposal to add `__func__` to C++ was [N1642](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1642.html)).

`__FUNCTION__` is a pre-standard extension that some C compilers support (including gcc and Visual C++); in general, you should use `__func__` where it is supported and only use `__FUNCTION__` if you are using a compiler that does not support it (for example, Visual C++, which does not support C99 and does not yet support all of C++0x, does not provide `__func__`).

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a gcc extension that is mostly the same as `__FUNCTION__`, except that for C++ functions it contains the "pretty" name of the function including the signature of the function.  Visual C++ has a similar (but not quite identical) extension, `__FUNCSIG__`.

For the nonstandard macros, you will want to consult your compiler's documentation.  The Visual C++ extensions are included in the MSDN documentation of the C++ compiler's ["Predefined Macros"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b0084kay.aspx).  The gcc documentation extensions are described in the gcc documentation page ["Function Names as Strings."](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Comment: Can you link to the C99 specification (there's a floating link in your source), for what looks like the winning answer?

Comment: @Matt:  Sure.  I added a link to the latest C++0x draft with paragraph reference as well, just so everything has a good reference.

Comment: @legends2k:  No, it is "an implementation-defined string" in C++11.  That's the actual language from the specification.  See §8.4.1[dcl.fct.def.general]/8.

Comment: Note that while both gcc and VC provide `__FUNCTION__`, they do slightly different things.  gcc gives the equivalent of `__func__`.  VC gives the undecorated, but still adorned, version of the name.  For a method named "foo", gcc will give you `"foo"`, VC will give `"my_namespace::my_class::foo"`.

Comment: MSVC [provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b0084kay.aspx) one more non-standard predefined macro - `__FUNCDNAME__` - the decorated name of the enclosing function.

Comment: MSVC also has another that shows the functions memory address in hex format: `__FUNCTIONW__`

Comment: What is curious is that I am using MSVC 2017 CE and when I type `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` it does show up in the list as being available and when I move my mouse over it, it does display information about the function name, however it does fail to compile.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I was surprised by this as well! See my question on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857887/pretty-function-in-visual-c

Comment: I have a little macro that detects the compiler and uses either `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__FUNCSIG__`, but I'd like to support a few more compilers if at all possible. Do any other compilers have a function signature macro, especially with template parameters? Edit - so far Clang, GCC, MSVC

Answer (score 176):

Despite not fully answering the original question, this is probably what most people googling this wanted to see.

For GCC:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl
              << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl
              << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
$ g++ test.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
main
main
int main(int, char**)
```

Comment: Same output from clang 3.5

Comment: Ok, but does `__func__` work when it's embedded in another function?

Lets say I have function1, it takes no arguments. function1 calls function2 that includes `__func__`, which function name will be printed, 1 or 2?

Comment: @MarcusJ why not try it yourself... the `__func__` is a macro, it will translate to whatever function you are currently in. If you put it into f1 and call f1 in f2, you will always get f1.

Comment: I was going to, then thought I'd ask.

I feel like it won't work and it's kind of a pain in the ass so I'll just keep it the way it is.

Comment: @Petr Strictly speaking `__func__` is a predefined identifier, not a macro.

Answer (score 91):

**`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` handles C++ features: classes, namespaces, templates and overload**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N {
    class C {
        public:
            template <class T>
            static void f(int i) {
                (void)i;
                std::cout << "__func__            " << __func__ << std::endl
                          << "__FUNCTION__        " << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl
                          << "__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            }
            template <class T>
            static void f(double f) {
                (void)f;
                std::cout << "__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            }
    };
}

int main() {
    N::C::f<char>(1);
    N::C::f<void>(1.0);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

Output:

```
__func__            f
__FUNCTION__        f
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ static void N::C::f(int) [with T = char]
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ static void N::C::f(double) [with T = void]
```

You may also be interested in stack traces with function names: [How to print a stack trace whenever a certain function is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c/54365144#54365144)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, GCC 8.3.0.

**C++20 `std::source_location::function_name`**

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <source_location>

void log(std::string_view message,
         std::source_location location = std::source_location::current()
) {
    std::cout << "info:"
              << location.file_name() << ":"
              << location.line() << ":"
              << location.function_name() << " "
              << message << '\n';
}

int f(int i) {
    log("Hello world!"); // Line 16
    return i + 1;
}

int f(double i) {
    log("Hello world!"); // Line 21
    return i + 1.0;
}

int main() {
    f(1);
    f(1.0);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
./main.out
```

Output:

```
info:source_location.cpp:16:int f(int) Hello world!
info:source_location.cpp:21:int f(double) Hello world!
```

so note how this returns the caller information, and is therefore perfect for usage in logging, see also: [Is there a way to get function name inside a C++ function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733056/is-there-a-way-to-get-function-name-inside-a-c-function/60491324#60491324)

The proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1208r5.pdf

The documentation says:

> constexpr const char* function_name() const noexcept;
>
> 6 Returns: If this object represents a position in the body of a function,
> returns an implementation-defined NTBS that should correspond to the
> function name. Otherwise, returns an empty string.

where NTBS means "Null Terminated Byte String".

Tested on  GCC 11.3 Ubuntu 22.04. It was not on GCC 9.1.0 with `g++-9 -std=c++2a`.

Answer (score 18):

`__func__` is documented in the C++0x standard at section 8.4.1. In this case it's a predefined  function local variable of the form:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name ";
```

where "function name" is implementation specfic. This means that whenever you declare a function, the compiler will add this variable implicitly to your function. The same is true of `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. Despite their uppercasing, they aren't macros. Although `__func__` is an addition to C++0x

```
g++ -std=c++98 ....
```

will still compile code using `__func__`.

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and `__FUNCTION__` are documented here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Function-Names.html#Function-Names. `__FUNCTION__` is just another name for `__func__`. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is the same as `__func__` in C but in C++ it contains the type signature as well.

Comment: `__func__` is not part of C++03.  It has been added in C++0x, but C++0x is not yet "the C++ standard," it is still in draft form.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis It is now, so clear the comments, to remove the noise

Answer (score 13):

For those, who wonder how it goes in VS.

MSVC 2015 Update 1, cl.exe version 19.00.24215.1:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename X, typename Y>
struct A
{
  template<typename Z>
  static void f()
  {
    std::cout << "from A::f():" << std::endl
      << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl
      << __func__ << std::endl
      << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
  }
};

void main()
{
  std::cout << "from main():" << std::endl
    << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl
    << __func__ << std::endl
    << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl << std::endl;

  A<int, float>::f<bool>();
}
```

output:

```
from main():
main
main
int __cdecl main(void)

from A::f():
A<int,float>::f
f
void __cdecl A<int,float>::f<bool>(void)
```

Using of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` triggers undeclared identifier error, as expected.

Comment: `void main()` is technically ill-formed. `main`, however defined in terms of arguments must return `int`.