# Visual C++ equivalent of __FILE__ , __LINE__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-construction

GCC compiler gives me the following macros:

- `__FILE__` so that I can print out the file name + directory.
- `__LINE__` so that I can print out the line number of where I'm printing from.
- `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` so that I can print out the pretty function name

Does Visual C++ have the equivalent of these macros? A side question is, are these standard for C++ compilers?

Comment: For people who might want to know more about these macros: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.0/gcc/Function-Names.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In VS2008, this:

```
struct A
{
    bool Test(int iDummyArg)
    {
        const char *szFile = __FILE__;
        int iLine = __LINE__;
        const char *szFunc = __FUNCTION__; // Func name
        const char *szFunD = __FUNCDNAME__; // Decorated
        const char *szFunS = __FUNCSIG__; // Signature

        printf("%s\n", szFile);
        printf("%d\n", iLine);
        printf("%s\n", szFunc);
        printf("%s\n", szFunD);
        printf("%s\n", szFunS);

        return true;
    }
};

int wmain(int argc, TCHAR *lpszArgv[])
{
    A a;
    a.Test(10);
}
```

will print this:

```
c:\source\test_projects\blah\blah.cpp
14
A::Test
?Test@A@@QAE_NH@Z
bool __thiscall A::Test(int)
```

(The line number is "wrong" since there was really some extra stuff at the top of my file.)

Answer (score 9):

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are standard, and I'm rather certain Microsoft compilers have essentially always had them.

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a gcc feature.

Answer (score 7):

For more portability in getting the current function name, you can try [BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/current_function.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes Visual C++ has them or an equivalent. See the responses here:

[What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-)
function-func/4384860#4384860

Also note that despite the upper case used, they aren't macros. They're variables.

Comment: They _are_ macro's. Just check the title of their MSDN page: [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/b0084kay.aspx)

Comment: @MSalters: hmmm ... according to the [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Function-Names.html) they're variables. Looks like VC++ implements it differently.

Answer (score 3):

I know that MSVC offers `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, both of which are Standard macros. They also offer `__FUNCTION__`, which I believe is what you're looking for,

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are standard since C89.  `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a GCCism.  `__func__` is a C99ism which (unlike GCCisms) may well be available in Visual C++; it is not precisely the same as `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` but it may be close enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Microsoft Visual Studio has `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. [Here are more MSVC macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).
2. Both are ANSI C++.
3. MSVC has `__FUNCTION__`, which is Microsoft-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Using [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) with [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) you can use this: `WHERE` macro.

Based on usage of:

- [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)
- [`__LINE__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

```
#include "string/ConstexprString.hpp"

#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)

// WHERE - const char* const should be used as temporary value
#define WHERE (string::make(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) + ":" + string::make(S2(__LINE__))).get()

// It is safe to store e.g. `constexpr auto where = WHERE_STR;`
#define WHERE_STR (string::make(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) + ":" + string::make(S2(__LINE__)))
```

### Example usage:

```
    // Called: void (anonymous namespace)::exampleUseCaseWhere(int):18
    std::cout << "Called: " << WHERE << std::endl;
```

Full & running [example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NNiGtWRMnJap0uLc)

### See:

- [src/acme/where.hpp](https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/src/acme/where.hpp)
- [src/string/ConstexprString.hpp](https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/src/string/ConstexprString.hpp)
- [src/acme/where_test.cpp](https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/test/src/acme/where_test.cpp)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.