# Displaying object name inside destructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor, destructor

Inside FileTwo.h

```
   #include"iostream"
    using namespace std ;
    class FileTwo{
    public:
      FileTwo(){
        cout<<"constructor for";//Here want to show the object for which the constructor has been called
      }
    ~Filetwo(){
      cout<<"Destructor for ";//Here want to show the object for which the destructor has been called 
    };
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include"Filetwo.h" 

int main(){
  FileTwo two ;
  return 0;
}
```

I know this sample program is very small , so we can able to find out the object for which the constructor and destructor has been called . But for big project is there any way to know the object name ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? The identifier of the variable? What would be the "name" in code like `foo(FileTwo());`?

Comment: you can't. c++ does not support reflections.

Comment: @zapredelom Reflection has nothing to do with it. Objects don't have names in C++, period. No amount of reflection would solve that. On the other hand C++ does have RTTI, which would provide the type information.

Comment: @Angew::yes identifier . in this case two .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. If your compile supports `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` or `__func__` (see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)), then you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class FileTwo{
  public:
    FileTwo(){
      cerr<<"constructor for "<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
    ~FileTwo(){
      cerr<<"Destructor for "<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
  FileTwo two;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I've also printed to `cerr` to ensure that this output gets flushed immediately and isn't lost if the program crashes. Also, since each object has a unique `*this` pointer, we can use that to see when particular objects are being made or getting killed.

The output for the above program on my computer is:

```
constructor for FileTwo::FileTwo() at 0x7fff641cde40
Destructor for FileTwo::FileTwo() at 0x7fff641cde40
```

Note that `__func__` is a C99 standard identifier. C++0x adds support in the form of an "implementation-defined string".

`__FUNCTION__` is a pre-standard extension supported by some compilers, including Visual C++ (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b0084kay.aspx)) and gcc (see [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)).

`__PRETTY_FUNCION__` is a gcc extension, which does the same sort of stuff, but prettier.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func) has more information on these identifiers.

Depending on your compiler, this may return the name of the class, though it may be a little mangled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
class FileTwo{
  public:
    FileTwo(){
      cerr<<"constructor for "<< typeid(*this).name() <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
    ~FileTwo(){
      cerr<<"Destructor for "<< typeid(*this).name() <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
  FileTwo two;
  return 0;
}
```

If you are trying to get the name of the variable to which the class is instantiated (`two` in your case), then there is not, to my knowledge, a way to do this. The following will emulate it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class FileTwo{
  public:
    FileTwo(const std::string &myName) : myName(myName) {
      cerr<<"constructor for "<< myName <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
    ~FileTwo(){
      cerr<<"Destructor for "<< myName <<" at "<<&(*this)<<endl;
    }
  private:
    std::string myName;
};

int main(){
  FileTwo two("two");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did your answer end up being, @Learner?

Comment: suppose in one of my function i want to return the function name using
_ _FUNCTION__ , then how to do that ?

Comment: @Richard::not yet get my answer . still searching for it . In your answer i can able to find the function name . but its not telling me which object is calling that function . we can able to get the address of that object . But is there any way to get the name of that object ?

Comment: @Learner, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` seems to do this, in my answer you can see that it prints "FileTwo::FileTwo()", which is the name of the class followed by the name of the function. Does this help?

Comment: Yes . i got some help from this . In my post constructor has been called since we have declared object two inside main . i want to show this name inside constructor . like whenever we are calling the constructor , two has been displayed on the screen .

Comment: @Learner, I posted yet another way to get the class name. If you are wanting the name of the variable to which the class is instantiated, I don't know of an easy trick for getting it (sorry!), but I have posted a method which emulates it.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you name the object, it is not possible. Something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class FileTwo {
  public:
    FileTwo(const std::string &myName) : name(myName){
      cout<<"constructor for" << name;//Here want to show the object for which the constructor has been called
    }
    ~Filetwo(){
      cout<<"Destructor for " << name;//Here want to show the object for which the destructor has been called 
    }

  private:
    std::string name;
};
```

and then change the main into :

```
#include"Filetwo.h" 
int main(){
  FileTwo two("two 11");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to name the object,all what you can do is making a private variable to hold the name.

```
using namespace std;
class myClass
{
    private:
    string className;

    public:
    ~myClass()
    {
        cout<<this->className;
    }
};
```

you can create setters and getters for you variable.

```
void SetName(string name)
{
   this->className = name;
}

string GetName()
{
   return this->className;
}
```