# Why only base class default constructor is called in virtual base multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

In multiple inheritance, I have a virtual `Base` class which is inherited by class `A` and class `B`. `A` and `B` are base classes of `AB`. Please see the code below. 
In constructor of `A` and `B`, `Base(string)` constructor is called. I am expecting to get following output:

```
Base::Base(std::string)

A::A()

B::B()
```

But I am getting following output:

```
Base::Base()

A::A()

B::B()
```

Why default constructor of `Base` is being called?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
        Base(){
                cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
        }
        Base(string n):name(n){
                cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
        }
private:
string name;
};

class A : public virtual Base {
public:
        A():Base("A"){
                cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
        }
private:
string name;
};

class B : public virtual  Base {
public:
        B():Base("B"){
                cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<endl;
        }
private:
string name;
};

class AB : public A, public B{

};

int main(){
        AB a;
}
```

Comment: Because the constructors of virtual base classes are called from
the most derived class. In your example, what argument do you expect `Base::Base( std::string )` to receive?

Comment: You are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func .

Comment: This makes sense. As in virtual base class we are going to have just one shared object, so which class ( A or B ) should construct it as they are passing different string to the constructor. If most derived class is constructing it, there is no confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The virtual base is constructed by the *most-derived* object. So `AB`'s constructor call the `Base` constructor, but since you didn't specify a constructor for `AB`, its default constructor just calls the default constructor of `Base`.

You could call the string-constructor from `AB` like this:

```
struct AB : A, B
{
    AB() : Base("hello"), A(), B() { }
};
```

Note that the constructors `A::A()` and `B:B()` do *not* call the `Base` constructor in this setup!