# Why virtual derive chain need to call virtual base class's ctor in every derived class's initialize list?

Tags: c++

i have three class like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(int a){}
};
class B: virtual public A
{
    public:
    B(char c):A(5){}
}
class C: virtual public B
{
    public:
    C():B("a"){} //VC++ tells me that "class A doesn't have default constructor
}
```

Why class C's constructor needs to call class A's constructor again?

Comment: C will call A's constructor instead of B now due to virtual inheritance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273524/why-only-base-class-default-constructor-is-called-in-virtual-base-multiple-inher


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/c-virtual-inheritance