# PSTR() on __FUNCTION__

Tags: c++, c, embedded, avr-gcc

Using `avr-gcc` it is possible to store data on Program Memory in order to save RAM. This is acomplished using [PROGMEM attribute](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html). AVR-libc also provides a macro, [PSTR()](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html), which can be used to with literal strings.

Now I'm trying to use `PSTR()` with [`__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

The following code works as expected,

```
display.message(__func__, 2);
display.message(__FUNCTION__, 2);
display.message(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, 2);
```

, while the compilation of any of these lines fails,

```
display.messageP(PSTR(__func__), 2);
display.messageP(PSTR(__FUNCTION__), 2);
display.messageP(PSTR(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__), 2);
```

, with the following error:

```
initializer fails to determine size of '__c'
```

The definition of PSTR, from WinAVR/avr/include/avr, explains the variable referenced on the error message:

```
# define PSTR(s) (__extension__({static char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))
```

This is not something general to macros, as `__FILE__` compile and work fine:

```
display.messageP(PSTR(__FILE__), 2);
```

Any ideas on what is causing this error, and if it possible to use PSTR() to insert function name on program memory?

Comment: Looks like those string literals cannot be placed in that space as they require special functions? to access them.  In truth, these names should be pretty darn small so I wonder if there is a real advantage to moving them there anyways.  I say this with no idea of the actual amount of RAM you have though.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan avr-libc provide functions to access variable in program memory; this is confirmed by the last line of code on the question, which works fine. I agree that these strings are small, but they are significant in embedded systems (with only a few Kbytes of RAM).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are not string literals, like `__FILE__`, but are created like static local char array variables to the function you are using them from. So, the `PSTR()` macro will fail since you cannot use an array variable to initialize another array variable like that.

`__func__` is described in C11, §6.4.2.2 ¶1:

> The identiﬁer `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function deﬁnition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where *`function-name`* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

[According to the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are just synonyms for `__func__` in C (`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is more verbose for C++).

Comment: Is there a way to get __func__ into program memory? By default the definition places it in RAM. Obviously people don't want to waste RAM on static debugging data.

Comment: The question was about avr-gcc, implying the AVR platform. It is a Harvard architecture with two memory spaces. Program memory is the device's flash memory, normally read-only. Since the devices only have limited RAM (16k is about the limit, typically 2-4k) you don't want to fill it with debug strings.

Comment: @MoJo: Thanks, for the clarification. It seems you will need to declare you own variables on a case by case basis if you have this requirement, or you have to modify the compiler to extend it to allow you to specify the memory target for the `__func__` variable.

Comment: I put in an enhancement request for GCC.