# how to get __FILE__, __func__ and __LINE__ macro working in single line?

Tags: c++11, macros

The accepted answer to the question [C++ concatenating __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343205/c-concatenating-file-and-line-macros) work for **FILE** and **LINE**, but I would like to add the **func** macro too.

```
#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)
#define S3(x) x

#define LOCATION __FILE__ " : " S3(__func__) " : " S2(__LINE__)
```

this gives error

```
log.cpp|15 col 15 error| note: in definition of macro ‘S3’
```

Also tried,

```
#define LOCATION __FILE__ " : " __func__ " : " S2(__LINE__)
```

gives error

```
log.cpp|30 col 9 error| note: in expansion of macro ‘LOCATION’
```

I understand that **LINE** was a integer hence needed #x, but **func** is a char array. How do I get this working? Any help?

Comment: `__func__` is not a macro.

Comment: How do you plan to use LOCATION?

Answer (score 2):

As cpplearner mentioned correctly `__func__` is not a macro, it's a special function-local predefined variable. I achieved desired result by

```
#define S1(x) #x
#define S2(x) S1(x)
#define LOCATION string(__func__) + " : " S2(__LINE__) + " : "
```

and I use it by sending the string to a wrapper log function

```
void log(string s) {
     cout << s <<endl;
}

void abc(){
    log(LOCATION + string("some message "));
}
```

Outputs:

```
abc : 23 : some message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
__func__ is a variable (not a macro unlike __FILE__ or __LINE__)
```

This related question [Treating __func__ as a string literal instead of a predefined identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298829/treating-func-as-a-string-literal-instead-of-a-predefined-identifier) has good explanation.