How to append static strings with __FUNCTION__ in clang
The following c++ code compiles fine with MSVC but doesn't compile with CLang.
void Test()
{
    auto str = __FUNCTION__ "." "Description";
}

why does this work for MSVC only? how do I make this work for clang? (. and Description can append without any issues in both compilers)
clang error: expected ';' at end of declaration

Note that "Test . Description" is not a solution, I want to use this in a macro and make static strings based on what function the macro is used in.

What version of CLang?  What version of C++ did you tell CLang to use?

To be clear, that's not standard C++ code. The name __FUNCTION__, because it contains two consecutive underscores, is reserved for use by the implementation. Whatever it does is up to the compiler writer. So consult your compiler's documentation.

related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298829/treating-func-as-a-string-literal-instead-of-a-predefined-identifier

@ThomasMatthews here is godbolt demonstration https://godbolt.org/z/8T8G871G4 I use the latest version

You don't need to complicate so much, you can simply do it as:
std::string{_ func _}.append(".").append("Description");

@PeteBecker Thanks, is there standard c++ alternative for this? something that just gives the function name and append it with some other static string at compile time?

As of C++ 20, std::source_location

In gcc and clang, __FUNCTION__ is not a string literal. It expands to a name of some unique local variable of type array of chars.

Please post the complete error message that points the location where ; is expected.

If clang is run with -E, it can be seen that __FUNCTION__ is not a macro. This also was noticed in the comment with the linked answer: In C++, __FUNCTION__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ have always been variables.
# 1 "/app/example.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 468 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "/app/example.cpp" 2

void Test()
{
    auto str = __FUNCTION__ ".Description";
}

You can make it like
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

void Test() {
  const auto str = __FUNCTION__ + ".Description"s;
}

