# qSetMessagePattern("%{file}(%{line}): %{message}") output "unkown(0)"

Tags: c++, qt, logging, qt5

I'm using `qSetMessagePattern` to format the output.

The weird thing is even I set `%{file}` and `%{line}`, I could only get `unknown` and `0` in my output. And so does the `%{function}`. The source and output are below:

```
qSetMessagePattern("%{file}(%{line}): %{message}");
qDebug() << "msg";
```

output:

```
unknown(0): msg
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm: you're building in Debug mode, right?

Comment: I think so. I use `install(TARGETS my_exe DESTINATION ${install_dir} CONFIGURATIONS Debug)` in CMakeLists.txt and `make install` to install my executable file.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add for the target you build:

```
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DQT_DEBUG -DQT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT)
```

Seems `-DQT_DEBUG` has priority when used along with `-DQT_NO_DEBUG`.

Answer (score 2):

add 
`DEFINES += QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT`
to your xxx.pro, 
and then, rebuild

```
make clean && make distclean && qmake && make
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: He's using CMake. This advice is still sound, but notice that there's a good reason for stripping out source information in release builds (they leak information about your application)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, 
It is CPPFLAGS in qmake. So add set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DQT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT") in CMake

Answer (score 1):

I used this hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012195/2656799 to bypass the problem. In qlogging.h ([see there](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtCore/qlogging.h.html#QMessageLogger)) you can see how debug macros defined:

```
#define qDebug QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
#define qInfo QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).info
#define qWarning QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).warning
#define qCritical QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).critical
#define qFatal QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).fatal
```

So my solution is to redefine them using standard file, line context macros:

```
#define logDebug    QMessageLogger(__FILE__,__LINE__, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
#define logInfo     QMessageLogger(__FILE__,__LINE__, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).info
#define logWarning  QMessageLogger(__FILE__,__LINE__, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).warning
#define logCritical QMessageLogger(__FILE__,__LINE__, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).critical
#define logFatal    QMessageLogger(__FILE__,__LINE__, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).fatal
```