# __LINE__ __FILE__ OR similar function in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to print caller function, line number and file name without throwing an error for normal debugging purpose in QML. I can print caller function name as follows

```
console.log("Caller Function Name"+arguments.callee.caller.name);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can override [`qInstallMessageHandler`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) default function and provide your custom function which also prints line number / caller. You can find an example in the linked documentation. Another partial example:

```
void loggingMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & msg)
{
    QString timeStr(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss:zzz"));
    QString contextString(QString("[%1  %2]").arg(context.file).arg(context.line));

    mutex.lock();

    QString level;
    if(logFile.isOpen())
    {
        switch (type) {
        case QtInfoMsg:     level = QString("INF"); break;
        case QtDebugMsg:    level = QString("DEB"); break;
        case QtWarningMsg:  level = QString("WAR"); break;
        case QtCriticalMsg: level = QString("CRT"); break;
        case QtFatalMsg:    level = QString("FTL"); break;
        }
        QTextStream stream(&logFile);
        stream << timeStr << " " << contextString << "\t"  << level << "\t"  << msg << endl;
        stream.flush();
    }

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    OutputDebugString(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(level.append(' ' + msg + '\n').utf16()));
#elif defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
    android_default_message_handler(type, context, level.append(" " + msg));
#else   // MACX || IOS || LINUX
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", level.append(" " + msg).toLocal8Bit().constData());
#endif
      mutex.unlock();
}
```

If `logFile` is open, logging data is wrote to that in a critical section delimited by a `QMutex` otherwise it is simply output to the standard output of each platform.

Whatever is the handler you define, it can be combined with categorized logging (available since Qt 5.2) to easily setup a custom logging facility tailored on your needs. You just need to define your logging categories, as described in [this blog post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/03/11/qt-weekly-1-categorized-logging/), and call [`qCDebug`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#qCDebug), [`qCInfo()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#qCInfo), [`qCWarning()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#qCWarning) and so on. Depending on the active categories (set via the static function [`setFilterRules()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#setFilterRules) of [`QLoggingCategory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html)) different logging info can be printed or skipped.

That's especially interesting now that Qt 5.8 is available. Since this release, **you can use categories *also* in QML**, i.e. you can call `console` functions and pass along a category, e.g.

```
function myFancyFunction() {
    // foo code
    console.log(myFancyCategory, "message");
    // bar code
}
```

Also, categories declaration can be done fully in QML via the ad hoc type [`LoggingCategory`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qtqml-loggingcategory.html).

### ADDENDUM (Qt < 5.0)

The proposed solution works in a Qt 5.0+ environment with categories fully usable with Qt 5.3+ and QML categories available in Qt 5.8+; in a Qt 4.x environment you should override [`qInstallMsgHandler`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) but you do not have a `QMessageLogContext`. That means you should manage file/line info outside the handler, e.g. you have to use [`Q_FUNC_INFO`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#Q_FUNC_INFO) or rely on `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in C++ (note that the latters have been removed in latest 5.x releases as e.g. discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29172116/2538363)).