# __FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__ for QML files?

Tags: qt, qml

As a project I am working on is getting bigger I am getting tired of writing comprehensive log messages, needed to find out what went wrong and where.

So it would be extremely useful if I can incorporate that information into the messages automatically. For C++ we have the convenient `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` macros, but I don't seem to find any for QML.

Note that there is `console.trace()` which outputs a trace in the console in the following format:

`onCompleted (qrc:/main.qml:72)`

So it includes function, file and line, which is all I need, therefore I assume there already exists a way to get those. Natural, `console.trace()` doesn't really quite cut it, because it directly outputs to the console, whereas I need those as strings to incorporate in my log messages.

So is there any way to get those?

Naturally I don't want to get them in the actual QML source, but the same way `console.trace()` does - on the spot where my `Log.error()` is invoked, so I can just `Log.error("some error")` instead of `Log.error("some error in " + file + ", at " + line + " while executing " + func)` which will actually be even more tedious than writing the whole thing manually.

Alternatively, I'd also appreciate if someone can point me to the implementation of the qml `console`, because I combed through the entire qtdeclarative code base for "console" and found nothing.

Note that I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340692/line-file-or-similar-function-in-qml?rq=1), however it isn't of use to me, because I need that for a specific subset of messages and don't want to override the default message handler for all output.

Answer (score 14):

`console.log`, `console.debug`, `console.info`, `console.warn` and `console.error` can be used to print debugging information to the console. The output is generated using the `qDebug`, `qWarning`, `qCritical` methods in C++ (see also [Debugging Techniques](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtdoc-online/debug.html) and how such functions are [implemented](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/qml/v8/qqmlbuiltinfunctions.cpp#n1422), especially [this internal function](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/qml/v8/qqmlbuiltinfunctions.cpp#n1478)). Setting the environment variable `QML_CONSOLE_EXTENDED` also prints the source code location of the call. For example,

```
export QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="[%{type}] %{appname} (%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"
```

Now the output looks like this,

[image: some_example]

This [link](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtdoc-online/debug.html) contains details about customizing the `QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN` environment variable.

Comment: I need to get those as strings, not print them in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although at a first glance it doesn't seem like it is possible to use it. Not without a way to find the call context.

Comment: @dtech , any wayout for this ?