# How to get current file name in code snippet

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, code-snippets

I am trying to create a code snippet which shall print some console logs with current file name and current method/tag name like the way we have `systr` in eclipse.

Although I am able to add code snippet in *Tools > Options > Text editor > Snippet*, I could not find any tag to retrieve current file name.

Example File (TestMyUI.js):

```
function doSomething{
console.log("TestMyUI.doSomething()");
}
```

Here I like to generate `console.log` using a template saved in snippets. So that for every place I type something like `consLog` it must auto complete the log filled with current file and method name. This is similar to what we have `systr` in eclipse IDE.

Comment: If I understand correctly, let us say your code calls a function `foo()`, then inside this function you want to print out the filename of this function ? Is that right ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show a small example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you looking for this?: [Predefined macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros) i.e. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. Since C++11, there is a (compiler-defined) `__func__` variable in every function: [`__func__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func)

Comment: @Scheff thanks for your answer. but it is more to do with the QT creator that i am looking for

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, it would be too tightly coupled with Creator, and a lot of people don't use Creator.

Comment: I don't think there's nothing more special than `__FILE__` in qt [qDebug not showing `__FILE__`,`__LINE__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24012108/995714), [`__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` for QML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41409273/995714), [`__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__FUNCTION__` usage in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597078/995714)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer of @dtech:

Reporing the file, line and function is already an integral part of logging in Qt. All you have to do is use it correctly. There is no need for a code snippet to do this, as all this information is already collected by `console.log` but not shown by default. All you have to do now is tell Qt to make it visible.

A way that is easier than creating a custom message handler is to simply register a message pattern (See [`qSetMessagePattern`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern)). With this you can register a pattern that should be used to format anything logged via QDebug (including QML). A simple example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    qSetMessagePattern("%{file}:%{line} %{function} -> %{if-category}%{category}: %{endif}%{message}");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    // ...
}
```

Now in your QML-file simply log anything, and your good to go. For example, the following code:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

Would output for this example (created with an actual test file):

```
qrc:/TestMyUI.js:11 doSomething -> qml: test
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response. Alas our project is in 4.8 QT. Any clue if we could set this with some API in this version

Comment: No Idea - I guess you will have to search the doc for that. (You should also consider updating - Qt4 is not maintained anymore!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get that info for QML files and integrate it into the output, you can use

`qInstallMessageHandler(QtMessageHandler handler)`

to install your own message handler function. Inside that function you will have a `QMessageLogContext` reference, which will give you access to more information, such as file name, line number, function name and so on.

```
void msgHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) {
  static QTextStream ts(stdout);
  static const char * err[] = {"", "WARNING: ", "ERROR!: ", "FATAL: ", ""};
  QString m = QString(err[type]) + context.category + "/" + context.file + "@" + QString::number(context.line) + "-" + context.function + ": " + msg;  
  ts << msg << endl;
}
```

Now, you may not want to process all messages in that manner, and limit it to some specific pattern, which can easily be achieved by incorporating a particular "header" in the message string and checking whether a particular message contains that or not, and proceed accordingly. For example:

```
console.log("test") // regular msg
console.log("?test") // custom msg handling
```

Naturally, you can use an array of headers to specify custom handling, save logs to different files, send network messages or emails in custom formats or whatever. Once you utilize a custom handler you can do with the messages whatever you want.

Comment: Hi @dtech. Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate may be an example would help me better understand the solution.

Comment: Well, it will allow you to do what the OP asks about - `print the some console logs with current file name and current method/tag name`. See the answer edit: