# How do I debug KWin's window switcher?

Tags: qt, debugging, qml, kde-plasma, window-managers

My `KWin`s' `window switcher` doesn't work well for months. I decide to debug it.

Flip/Cover Switch work well. Others don't. I want to use Big Icon.

I think I should start with the `qml` script, then maybe the KWin C code.

I don't know how to start with `qml` script debugging. ( Where can I write debug messages ? )

Comment: https://qmlbook.github.io/ .  There are events, such as `Component.onCompleted: { console.log('here') }`.

Comment: @RossRogers Log didn't show up at kwin's output. Will the qdbus receive the debug message?

Comment: I have no clue where it'd show up.  Barring other options, I'd recommend doing a `console.log('MY_SUPER_DUPER_UNIQUE_WEIRD_STRING')` and then searching the entire system:   `sudo grep -R MY_SUPER_DUPER_UNIQUE_WEIRD_STRING /`  :-P

Comment: @RossRogers Thanks. Whole disk grep didn't work for me. However KWin got itself work somehow, and I can't completely recall what I did to make it work! Quite annoying.

Comment: Uhm...may [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41342630/2538363) help you for logging?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thanks. this answer you post looks worth a shot. But I'm now sure switching from `Rendering Backend` from `OpenGL` to `XRender` solved my `windows switcher`'s strange behaviour problem. So it's related to collaboration of OpenGL and KWin. I believe I can bypass `qml debugging` and jump to `C debugging` now, I think.