# C++ macro to get full function path and declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to get full function path and declaration in code via macro or some compiler magic. I have this code ([click here to run](http://cpp.sh/6trdl)):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS {

    struct Foo {
        static int sum(int a, int b) {
            std::cout << "This is from " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " @ " <<     __func__ << std::endl;
            return a+b;
        }

        static int sum(int a, int b, int c) {
            std::cout << "This is from " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " @ " <<     __func__ << std::endl;
            return a+b+c;
        }

   };
}

int main() {
    NS::Foo::sum(1,2);
    NS::Foo::sum(1,2, 3);
}
```

And I get the output:

```
This is from /some/where/main.cpp:7 @ sum
This is from /some/where/main.cpp:12 @ sum
```

**My questions are:**

- How do I get the full path of `sum` function invoked?`(NS::Foo::sum)`
- How can I get the full function declaration with argument types?( `sum(int, int)` or `sum(int, int, int)`)

I am interested in mainstream compilers: `Clang, GCC, Microsoft C++ compiler`

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for edit. I understand it, it's just a bad habit.

Comment: There is a reason macros are processed by the **pre**processor. They are textual replacements and have no idea about the "normal" C++ code (btw. **this* is the same for all pre-processors).

Comment: Are you trying to detect the full path where the file is located in?

Comment: What do you mean by the "full path of sum function"? Functions don't have paths. Do you mean the fully qualified name ("NS::Foo::sum")?  (If you do, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)).

Comment: @sameerasy: I understand the question that OP wants to show where the _method_ is invoked.

Comment: Note the `sum` is a _method_, not a simple _function_.

Comment: @molbdnilo I've edited the question

Comment: @Olaf : C++ is not Java is not C++, `sum` is a _member function_. ;-D

Comment: @ildjarn: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming). There's more than C++ and Java!

Comment: @Olaf : The smiley implied the joke, but if you want to be pedantic, the C++ standard has no notion or definition of the term 'method'. And you made the point that we're discussing C++, after all. ;-]

Comment: You missed the point. _method_ is the standard term. The C++ standard does also not define some other common terms. Yet they do apply. But thanks for providing the correct term. I prefer C and Python.

Comment: @Olaf : And you're still missing the point that it was a joke.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis : Also of note here, although not immediately usable that I'm aware of, is [N4519](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4519.pdf)'s proposed `std::experimental::source_location`, which is part of the Library Fundamentals v2 TS.

Comment: Notice that C++11 has anonymous functions (e.g. *lambda*s).... You probably won't be able to get something fancy in that case

Answer (score 3):

Answering for GCC.

Checkout the [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) macro. I've found it in the defintion of `assert` macro in `<assert.h>`. Perhaps same could be found for other compilers and libc implementations.

Comment: Nice! It's even supported in Clang. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, `__FUNCSIG__` can give you a lot about the function.

`__FUNCSIG__` will give you full function signature
`__FUNCDNAME__` gives magnled name.
`__FUNCTION__` is just for function name.

Comment: Seems to be what I needed for visual studio. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to limit yourself to a single compiler, and don't fancy writing a pre-processor ifdef chain yourself, boost has already defined a macro [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](http://www.boost.org/libs/assert/current_function.html) which is defined as the full function signature macro that's defined on the used compiler. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in gcc and other compilers that support that, `__FUNCSIG__` where that is supported (msvc), also supports some lesser used compilers and falls back to `__func__` as defined by the C standard (or a static placeholder if even that's not supported).