# How can i disable zoom in an iOS WKWebVIew in only one page?

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

The app i'm working on has a web view that navigates through a whole flow filling some forms, at the end shows a finish screen with a button to navigate to the home.
My boss want to disable zoom in the form screens but no in the last one.

Also i've tried with the following code but it just doesn't work:

```
webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable zoom in WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452034/disable-zoom-in-wkwebview)

Comment: It worked for disable the zoom, but how can i enable it again in the las screen?

Comment: You can track URL changes in the WKWebView (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213185/wkwebview-function-for-detecting-if-the-url-has-changed) and enable/disable zoom accordingly.