# Usage of __FUNCTION__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in non GCC compiler

Tags: c++, windows, unix

I'm using `__FUNCTION__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macros in my code and learned that the code needs to compile under compilers other than GCC. Are these macros part of the standard? or GCC extension? Should I use `__func__` instead?

Comment: No these macros aren't part of the standard.

Comment: `__func__` is standardized from C++11, hence, yes, you should prefer it

Comment: FWIW, `__func__` is a const static variable, not a macro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between \_\_PRETTY\_FUNCTION\_\_, \_\_FUNCTION\_\_, \_\_func\_\_?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

Comment: I've been using `__FUNCTION__` in code since the 90's across different compilers. If it's not a *standard* as per the language lawyers, then it *practically is a standard*....  You've asked a couple of different questions on other posts about *will this macro work on other compilers*.   Porting C/C++ to work across compilers has a lot of annoyances and quirks.  The function, line, and file macros are the **least** of these issues that come up. :)

Comment: They are also different. So in MSVC you can do `std::cerr << “Error in “ __FUNCTION__;` because it’s a macro but in clang is doesn’t compile because it’s a static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these macros part of the standard?

No.

> Should I use `__func__` instead?

`__func__` is standard (and is not a macro). If a compiler does not support the others, you can fall back to this - as long as the compiler supports a recent standard. On an older compiler, you'll have to use a compiler specific macro.

Note that the different macros may provide varying levels of information beyond the function name. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in particular provides useful additional information (namespace qualified, full signature, template arguments).

If you want the prettiest function name a compiler has to offer (if any), you need to detect the compiler with pre defined macros and research what each compiler version support. Or, if you don't like re-implementing what others have already done for you, you could use `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`.

Comment: BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

- `__FUNCTION__` is available pretty much everywhere but it is just a simple function name
- `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with GCC compatible compilers like GCC, Clang and Intel's compiler and even with compilers like [Sun Studio 12](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7598/giphl/index.html)'s one.
- beware, `__func__` is not a macro
- Visual Studio C++ compiler has [`__FUNCSIG__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) (you probably want this) and `__FUNCDNAME__` (less useful as it is the full decorated name)