# __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

While playing around with Visual C++ from Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.6 to be exact) I noticed that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` from GCC seems to work! - to some degree at least…

It did show up along suggestions while typing:
[image]

Also it had its value shown in tooltip as expected:
[image]

And yet compiling the code using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` results in an error:

```
error C2065: '__PRETTY_FUNCTION__': undeclared identifier
```

So, is there any way to make it work in Visual C++? Some include perhaps? Or some special compilation settings? (I think I'm using default ones.) Why would it work in shown examples, but not in actual use?!

Note, that I'm not looking for Visual C++ alternatives for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. I know them already. I'm just surprised and curious about the behavior here.

Comment: Remember that Intellisense is a different compiler than what is used to compile your code.

Comment: @drescherjm Is it? That I didn't knew... Kind of surprising actually! (To me at least...) Where do you know this from? And does it explain this effect or is just a possible reason?

Comment: That's interesting. I could understand this happening with some third party IDE like Eclipse etc. But apparently Microsoft's own IDE knows something about `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, even though their compiler doesn't support it?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense/

Comment: Yeah that's "pretty" funny to be fair

Comment: EDG's [C++ Front End](http://www.edg.com/docs/edg_cpp.pdf) documentation mentions it on page 71 - "1.13 Predefined Macro" together with Micsosoft's own `__FUNCSIG__`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> So, is there any way to make it work in Visual C++? Some include perhaps? Or some special compilation settings? (I think I'm using default ones.) Why would it work in shown examples, but not in actual use?!

No.

The Visual Studio uses the [Edison Design Group](http://www.edg.com/) C++ Front End for the InteliSense, as explained in the Visual C++ Team Blog's [Rebuilding Intellisense](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/), and not the Microsoft C++ compiler. This means that some of the features available to the Intellisense are not available in compile time.

EDG's [C++ Front End documentation](http://www.edg.com/docs/edg_cpp.pdf) mentions that its supports some of the GCC pre-defines like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` on page 71 - "1.13 Predefined Macros" together with Microsoft's `__FUNCSIG__`.

You can even see the version of the EDG by typing `__EDG_VERSION__` and hovering over it.

Comment: There is a way to make it sort-of work. Include the following:
`#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__`

Comment: full macro check `#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__
#endif`

Comment: Pedantic but note that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a reserved identifier, best practice not to #define it

Answer (score 8):

You can emulate it pretty well by putting this in some common header (for example, your precompiled header, if you're using that):

```
#if !defined(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) && !defined(__GNUC__)
#define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__
#endif
```

It doesn't evaluate to exactly the same as **PRETTY_FUNCTION**, but it's a human-readable representation of the function name with argument types.

Comment: This does not work in gcc/clang. You will get the error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/774vnn5Kr

Comment: For people who just copy-and paste, I improved the solution to be GNU compatible out of the box.

Comment: It seems that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`  is not a regular macro, and its availability cannot be checked like that with `#ifdef` or similar.

Comment: @LauriNurmi It can not be a macro because the preprocessor does not understand what a function it. Both C and C++ specify `__func__` as a magic identifier and so are all extensions/alternatives of it.