# How to silence GCC pedantic (-Wpedantic) warning regarding __FUNCTION__

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I am printing out (printf) the name of the function as I enter it by using the "__FUNCTION__" predefined macro (in gcc and clang). However, if I use -Wpedantic, I get this warning:

> warning: ISO C does not support ‘__FUNCTION__’ predefined identifier
>   [-Wpedantic]

How do I silence that warning?

Comment: In C11, it's `__func__`

Comment: `-Wno-pedantic`?

Comment: @user3386109 `__func__` does the trick! You should put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Scooter use backticks ` ` to quote code excerpts in comments (and in posts in general)

Comment: @Scooter Ok, let me look up the section in the C11 spec.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Got it,thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard compliant function identifier is `__func__`

From §6.4.2.2 of the C11 specification

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator
>   as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function
>   definition, the declaration
>   `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`
>   appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing 
>   function.

I believe that `__func__` was added in C99.

Answer (score 14):

There is no reason to use `__FUNCTION__`.

`__func__` is the standard one (C99, [C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1), C17). C11 6.4.2.2p1:

> 1. The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
>    ```
>    static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
>    ```

From [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html):

> `__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`, provided for backward compatibility with old versions of GCC.

And if you want to know how old, `__func__` appeared in [GCC 2.95](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/c99status.html), released **July 31, 1999**. Mind you, you do not need `__FUNCTION__` for *anything else* but **to support GCC 2.94 or earlier**. If you do, then that warning is probably least of your worries.

---

However, `__func__` isn't available in C89/90 mode either, so you'd get a warning there. If you care about ISO diagnostics, then you need to use a more recent revision. Modern GCCs default to GNU C11 or C17 already.

---

See also:  [What's the difference between `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

Answer (score 2):

The `-Wpedantic` option is used to:

Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

`__FUNCTION__` is a GCC extension. However `__func__` is a predefined identifier in C11. I understand this is part of C99 as well.

Committee draft for C11 (N1570) states that:

> **6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers**
>   Semantics
>   1. The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char _ _func_ _[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

Answer (score 0):

Do no use `-Wpedantic` unless you try to adhere to the ANSI C standard, which obviously does not support the __FUNCTION__ keyword.

Use `-Wall -Wextra` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly thought that pedantic had some function other than ANSI C compatibility.

Comment: It does have functions other than ANSI C compatibility and you would be well served leaving it in your compile string and addressing the error with a preprocessor conditional that provides `_FUNCTION_` in the event it is not provided by your compiler (you may want to add `-Wshadow` as well)