# Replicating the behavior of __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, cross-platform

Where in GCC is the behavior of C++’s `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` defined? I want to replicate its functionality in Visual Studio.

It’s my understanding that I could [replace `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with either `__FUNCTION__` or `__FUNCSIG__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4384825),¹ but that, then, I’d lose the ability to compile the code on macOS.

How do include `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`’s functionality in code that I want to be able to compile in, say, both Visual Studio and Xcode.

---

1. Apologies if the answer to my question is in [the text I’m linking to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4384825) or in the resources it mentions.

Comment: So you want to define `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` so your code compiles on MSVC, rather than defining `__FUNCTION__` so it compiles on MacOS?

Comment: Instead of saying "make it like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`" which may change with g++ version and platform, why don't you give examples of what you are getting and what you want instead?  BTW `__func__` is the standard-compliant name for `__FUNCTION__`, it should be supported on Mac.

Comment: *"Where in GCC is the behavior of C++’s `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` defined?"* - what do you want to know - where it is in the source code, where GCC docs discuss it...?  The question doesn't seem at all relevant to your seeming functional requirements, which are easily satisfied with the `#if` / `#else` per-OS selection everyone's suggesting.

Comment: @BenVoigt I‘m trying to run [this code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180926143331id_/bioinfo.umassmed.edu/bootstrappers/guides/main/cxx_numeric_limits.html#numeric-limits) while asking the question without so much specificity that the answer couldn’t be used outside of that code’s context. Neither using `__func__` in Visual Studio nor using `__FUNCTION__` in Xcode replicated `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`’s behavior for me.

Comment: @Lucas: Of course it does not.  That code requires your compiler to generate a function name that is character-for-character identical to the compiler you designed it with, while the Standard specifically calls out the name produced by `__func__` (and by RTTI) as implementation-defined.  Your code may even break when using a different gcc version.

Comment: You are likely, however, to be happier starting with `typeid(T).name()` than with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Answer (score 6):

Define your own macro that refers to `__FUNCTION__` or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` based on your compiler:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define MY_FUNCTION_MACRO __FUNCTION__ // or __FUNCSIG__
#else
#define MY_FUNCTION_MACRO __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif
```

And then use `MY_FUNCTION_MACRO` throughout your cross-patform code.

Note that `MY_FUNCTION_MACRO` will still produce different strings from between VC++ and GCC/Clang. This is unavoidable and gets you as close as you can get.

For example:

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << MY_FUNCTION_MACRO << std::endl;
}
```

will produce "main" when using `__FUNCTION__` or "int __cdecl main(void)" when using `__FUNCSIG__` in VC++, whereas `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` produces "int main()" in GCC/Clang.

Comment: I think this is close to correct. I’m wondering why (even after using your `MY_FUNCTION_MACRO` solution and changing the `uint`s to `unsigned int`s) the output of each line in [`main()` in this code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180926143331id_/bioinfo.umassmed.edu/bootstrappers/guides/main/cxx_numeric_limits.html#numeric-limits), that uses the `typeStr` template, still outputs `indeterminate` when run using Visual Studio.

Comment: @Lucas that code you linked is trying to parse the result string of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. `__FUNCSIG__` will get you close in Visual Studio, but doesn't produce exactly the same output.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering about this myself, found your post, and did some more digging. Here's some answers and more that I discovered...

### Where in GCC is the behavior of C++’s `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` defined?

A recursive search for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` within [the gcc source code mirrored on github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc) suggested that its behavior is mostly defined through `DECL_PRETTY_FUNCTION_P` in [gcc/cp/pt.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/pt.cc). This in turn sees to `cp_make_fname_decl` being invoked from [gcc/cp/decl.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/decl.cc). And that builds a declaration for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Currently - as of my reading of this code and experience using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` - gcc provides a locally scoped, read only, constant expression, character array type of value.
I.e., by its naming convention, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` may look like a macro (that's what I'd assumed), but by its current implementation (in gcc), it's instead a **locally scoped**, character array.

### How do I include `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`’s functionality in code that I want to be able to compile in, say, both Visual Studio and Xcode?

Xcode by default I understand is using an Apple version of clang. Clang is more similar to gcc with respect to this question, than to msvc. So if by Xcode, you mean to use the default compiler, that'd be clang which similarly supports `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

With this in mind, I like [cscrimage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56283414/7410358) using `__FUNCSIG__` for msvc and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` otherwise:

```cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define MY_FUNCTION_MACRO __FUNCSIG__
#else
#define MY_FUNCTION_MACRO __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif
```

### What To Expect

Using the abort sort of code within a function such as the following demonstrates the formats of these values for different compilers:

```cpp
template <typename T> std::string Name()
{
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
   return std::string {__PRETTY_FUNCTION__};
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
   return std::string {__FUNCSIG__};
#else
   return "not supported by compiler";
#endif
}

template <typename T> struct Other {};
using F = Other<int>;
```

A statement like:

```cpp
std::cout << Name<F>() << '\n';
```

On gcc 12.2 yields:

```
std::string Name() [with T = Other<int>; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
```

And on msvc 19.22 yields:

```
class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Name<struct Other<int>>(void)
```

That's pretty compiler dependent and clang is slightly different from gcc as well.

### Normalizing The Values

We could however use something like `std::regex_replace` with compiler dependent `std::regex` values to parse these into a more similar format between these compilers. I didn't find any documentation from gcc nor msvc that guaranteed what this format will be so I wouldn't expect it to stay the same between all releases of compilers either.

In my case (that got me to dig into this), I was particularly concerned about *stringifying* types and built on these techniques using the template type parameter as the value I intended to return from the replacement. Here's that code as an example that accounts for differences between msvc, clang, and gcc:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string Name()
{
    // Ideally return string unique to the type T...
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    // template <typename T> string Name() { return string{__FUNCSIG__}; }
    // enum class Fruit {APPLE, PEAR};
    // std::cout << Name<Fruit>() << '\n';
    // produces:
    // class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Name<enum Fruit>(void)
    return std::regex_replace(__FUNCSIG__, std::regex(".* __cdecl [^<]+<(.*)>\\(void\\)"), "$1");
#elif defined(__clang__)
    // template <typename T> string Name() { return string{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__}; }
    // enum class Fruit {APPLE, PEAR};
    // std::cout << Name<Fruit>() << '\n';
    // produces: std::string Name() [T = Fruit]
    return std::regex_replace(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, std::regex(".*T = (.*)\\].*"), "$1");
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    // template <typename T> string Name() { return string{__PRETTY_FUNCTION__}; }
    // enum class Fruit {APPLE, PEAR};
    // std::cout << Name<Fruit>() << '\n';
    // produces: std::string Name() [with T = Fruit; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]
    return std::regex_replace(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, std::regex(".*T = (.*);.*"), "$1");
#else
    return {}; // not unique but maybe still helpful at avoiding compiler issues
#endif
}

template <typename T> struct Other {};
using F = Other<int>;

int main()
{
   std::cout << Name<F>() << '\n';
}
```

With that, on gcc 12.2 and clang trunk we get `Other<int>`, and on msvc 19.22 we get `struct Other<int>` - see the full code at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dG7MM7M3e). This was close enough for my purposes.

Regular expressions for instead returning a commonly formatted function signature looks more involved (depending of course on exactly how common a format one wants) but I don't see why that couldn't be done also.

### Some Alternatives

If you can use boost, you may want to look into [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/current_function.hpp) or [`boost::core::demangle`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) depending on whether you just want code to pick the  variable for you to use on your platforms or whether you're more interested in re-using code that's already been written to give you the formatting. And if you have RTTI enabled, you can use something like `boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name())`. I notice however that for functions, this will strip off the function name and just provide a readable function signature for it. It also seems like `demangle` used between clang and msvc isn't returning a completely platform independent signature for the function either.

Or, if you can use C++20 or newer and it's the function signature and name you're wanting, [`std::source_location::function_name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/function_name) looks interesting. It's implementation defined too however.