# I don't understand when the constructor is called in this example

Tags: c++

Hi I have been trying to analyze the following code that uses operation overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DBG(str) cout << str << endl

class Integer {
    int n;
public:
    Integer(int _n) : n(_n) { DBG("A"); };
    Integer(const Integer& i) : n(i.n) { DBG("B"); };

    Integer& operator=(const Integer& i) { DBG("C"); n = i.n; return *this; };
    Integer& operator+=(const Integer& i) { DBG("D"); n += i.n; return *this; };

    friend Integer operator+(const Integer& a, const Integer& b);
    friend Integer operator*(const Integer& a, const Integer& b);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Integer& i);

};

Integer operator+(const Integer& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("E"); return Integer(a.n + b.n);
}
Integer operator*(const Integer& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("F"); return Integer(a.n * b.n);
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Integer& i) {
    DBG("G"); os << i.n; return os;
}

int main() {
    Integer n1(1), n2(2);
    Integer n = 5 + n1 + 2 * n2;

    cout << n << endl;
}
```

and the result comes out to be...

```
A // constructor called when n1 is created
A // constructor called when n2 is created
A // when is this called?
A // when is this called?
F // called when 2 * n2 is operated
A // called when Integer(a.n * b.n) is created in the multiplication function
E // called when 5 + n1 is operated
A // called when Integer(a.n + b.n) is created in the addition function
E // called when (5 + n1) + (2 * n2) is operated
A // called when Integer is created in the addition function
G // called when n is printed using cout
5 // value of n
```

Now what I'm having trouble with the most is the third and fourth print of A. In the sentence `Integer n = 5 + n1 + 2 * n2;` the object n is being created and the right value is assigned to n, so a copy constructor should be called? What I think should happen is the constructor should be called for making a temporary object of `(5 + n1 + 2 * n2)` and then by copying it to n, the copy constructor should be called. What am I understanding wrong?

Could you please explain what is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make your constructor print out the value of `n` to help trace what's happening.

Comment: Can you place a break-point on DBG("A") and check the call-stack?

Comment: `Integer n = 5 + n1 + 2 * n2;` The `5` is converted to an `Integer` object, which prints out `A`. Same goes for the `2`

Comment: You should step through the code in a debugger to see what's going on. That said, my guess is that the third and fourth "A" markers come from converting 5 and 2 to `Integer`. You're right about the copy constructor that creates `n`.

Comment: Questions like this may also depend on the version of C++ that you are using, and whether you are compiling in debug vs release (i.e. guaranteed copy elision).

Comment: You could try making your `Integer(int _n)` constructor `explicit` and see where the compiler points at errors.

Comment: try declaring Integer constructor as  `explicit` ; you will understand the reason :)

Comment: *What I think should happen...* -- If what you state will give you the correct result, guess what?  You're right.  The compiler is also right.  That's the issue -- a compiler can call the copy constructor in any way to construct the object.  Of course, the compiler writers minimize the calls as best as possible (and in some cases, must be copy elision).

Comment: Note that there are better ways to create a macro to trace the function calls. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func

With GCC, you can have `#define DBG() std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';`

Comment: Thank you. All of these suggestions helped a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
Integer n = 5 + n1 + 2 * n2;
```

There is no `operator+` for `int` and `Integer`, but compiler silently did a [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) from `int` to `Integer`, since by default all single argument constructors can be used as conversion method.
Here is [your live code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/12Zv4ySXr29agTTH) (improved a bit).

This is one of dangerous features of C++ so there is `explicit` keyword to be used before constructor. If you add it:

```
explicit Integer(const Integer& i) : n(i.n) { DBG("B"); };
```

Compiler will report an error since implicit conversion now can't be performed and there is no `operator+(int, const Integer&)` and `operator*(int, const Integer&)`.

Comment: Thank you for a clear  answer. So if int is implicitly converted to Integer, what does i.n really mean? Can 5 have member variables?

Comment: Defining constructor which can be called with single argument by default compiler can use as conversion method. In such situation compiler creates temporary unnamed object, which will be auto destroyed after line was executed.

Comment: There is tool to decompose implicit code: https://cppinsights.io/s/c11fe56f

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator+` and `operator*` functions receive an `const Integer&` as parameter.

When this line is calculated (`5 + n1 + 2 * n2`) 5 and 2 will be auto-converted to `Integer`.

If you want them to not be converted, you should consider creating operators for `int` as parameter.

**EDIT**: You can also use explicit constructor.

For example: `explicit Integer(int _n){...}`

//thanks for the comment @formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: better yet to declare the constructor as explicit to prevent implicit conversions

Answer (score 0):

Friend function is used in operator overloading only when the first parameter of the operator function is not an object of the target class for which the operator function is defined.
In your case, `Integer`:

```
Integer operator+(const Integer& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("E"); return Integer(a.n + b.n);
}
Integer operator*(const Integer& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("F"); return Integer(a.n * b.n);
}
```

, the first parameter is indeed an object of type `Integer` which is your target class. What you probably want is to be able to use your `Integer` object as operands along with primitive integer types.
Change your friend function signatures to:

```
Integer operator+(const int& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("E"); return Integer(a + b.n);
}
Integer operator*(const int& a, const Integer& b) {
    DBG("F"); return Integer(a * b.n);
}
```

Note that `a` is used instead of `a.n` because when an operator function is defined as friend, both operands are passed as parameters.(unlike non-friend operator functions where the first operand is a calling object). So the `a` contains a value of type `int` and not a value of type `Integer`.

> The anonymous calls to the constructor containing `DBG("A")` is a result of the implicit conversions happening when 5 and 2 are being converted from `int` to `Integer`.

This is unreliable although your code may work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for great answers