# C++: Create a (sort of) "decorator" to self document / self print debug info about code

Tags: c++, debugging

I have for debugging purposes created following workflow.

I defined a global macro

```cpp
#define PRINT_CALL(x) std::cout << "(CALL) " << x << std::endl
```

to notify whenever something is called. Trivially it is used like so:

```cpp
void foo() {
    PRINT_CALL("foo()");
    // do stuff
}
```

This makes debugging much easier in my use case. Is there a way to automate this? Here is what I had in mind in **totally illegal** C++ syntax:

```cpp
#define_decorator call_me(x) std::cout << "(CALL) " << x << std::endl

@call_me
void foo() {
    // do stuff
}
// ==> resulting in the exact same outcome as above.
```

I hope you get the idea. As I said, syntax is obviously trash; since I don't know of such a functionality and didn't find any useful information online, maybe someone knows a hack. Appreciate all answers!

Comment: With [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), your MACRO can be simplified, and so, your decorator is simply `PRINT_CALL();` as first instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really want to litter your code with debug annotations like this, you could use any of `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` etc., depending on your compiler and the language standard you are using.
I.e. define the macro like this

```
#define PRINT_CALL() std::cout << "(CALL) " << __func__ << std::endl
```

and use it like so

```
void foo() {
    PRINT_CALL(); // No need to rewrite the name 'foo'
    // do stuff
}
```

See here for more:
[What's the difference between __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __func__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func)

However I would strongly advise against this and consider using a debugger and breakpoints.

Comment: You're welcome :) And you can use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` to access more debug information.