# typeid().name() and consteval function problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, consteval

I am using MSVC 19, and get an error while compiling the following code.  Is there any way to get `type_info` and `name` of the object in `consteval` functions?

```
class CChTest
{
    public:
        static consteval const char*    test()
        {
            const char* ChReturn = typeid(CChTest).name();

            // ...
            // ...

            return ChReturn;
        }
};
```

Comment: `consteval` must be evalued at compile time, but `typeid` is known only at runtime, therefore use `constexpr` instead.

Comment: @metablaster, sure... but I need to use consteval for performance.

Comment: It's impossible to evalueate `typeid` operator at compile time.

Comment: @metablaster thanks.  any other way ?

Comment: Notes: 1) Any time you need to know the true type of a variable art runtime you've already pretty much lost your shot at good performance. 2) The information you get from `name` is very loosely specified. [Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name): "No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program." There aren't many good uses for `name`.

Comment: @metablaster `typeid` itself is allowed here in at compile-time. It is only the `name` member function which is not marked `constexpr` causing a problem. And with C++23 `operator==` of `std::type_info` is even `constexpr`, so `typeid` isn't completely useless in the context at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get class name at compile time there is no standard solution yet.

The [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) Type Index library does the job very well for over a decade. Its header only, you just need to include the `boost` directory containing the headers to use it in your project.

- [Documentation of Boost Type Index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html)
- [Usage examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_typeindex/examples.html)

Its build on to of macros like [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765). You can use these directly, but it depends on your compiler and even the specific compiler version, at what position in the string the type name is. So its better to let a very well tested and maintained library to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate the class name at compile time, declare a `static` variable consisting of a predefined name, as follows:

```
class CChTest
{
public:
    static consteval const char* test()
    {
        const char* ChReturn = name;

        // ...
        // ...

        return ChReturn;
    }

private:
    static constexpr const char* name = "CChTest";
};

int main()
{
    CChTest test;
    std::cout << test.test();

    return 0;
}
```

This means you'll have to maintain class names yourself.

To make it work with inheritance, let each derived class `override` the method, which means you need to make it `virtual consteval`.