# Pass function name as character pointer to pthread_create in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to create a pthread using pthread_create function and pass the function name as

```
char *function_name="get_time";

int rc = pthread_create(&thread_arr[threadNum], NULL,
    *function_name, (void *) output_cur_node->data);
```

Also tried using `(void*)&function_name`

This doesn't seem to enter the function `get_time()`.

Instead, When I use below

```
int rc = pthread_create(&thread_arr[threadNum], NULL,
    get_time, (void *) output_cur_node->data);
```

it works fine.

Please advise as to what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass addr of function, but you are trying to pass address of a string

Comment: How do i solve this? basically, I don't know the function names in advance. Rest of my code reads an xml and obtains function names from there in form of strings.

Comment: you need to maintain function name to address mapping . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349761/get-called-function-name-as-string for details

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of pthread_create is as follows:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

3rd argument has to be of function pointer which is of type

> void *(*start_routine) (void *)

So whenever you are trying to pass the argument by doing this

```
char *function_name="get_time";
(void*)&function_name
```

effectively means **void*** type which does not matches with the above type. Hence compile time error would be reported.