# How to print array name in function from argument?

Tags: c

I have a function like this:

```
foo(int a[], int b);
```

and I want to print the name of the array in the function. If I call

```
foo(cards, 5);
```

I want to print this: `array name:cards;array size:5`. How should I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349761/get-called-function-name-as-string

Comment: No, it's not - that deals with getting the enclosing function's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  By the time your program is executing, the name "cards" that was used in the source code is no longer available.  But you can do:

```
void foo(int *a, int b, const char *name);
...
foo(cards, 5, "cards");
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a wrapper macro.

```
#define STR(v) #v

#define FOO(name, value) do{ fprintf(stderr, "array name:%s;array size:%d\n", STR(name), value);foo(name, value); }while(0)
```

Use `FOO(cards, 5);` instead of.