# How to get the name of the function that calls the current function?

Tags: c, function, debugging, trace

I know that one can use **func** to get the current function name statically.

[Get called function name as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349761/get-called-function-name-as-string)

But if I want to get the function that calls this function, it has to be done dynamically.

Is there a way to do so in C (without adding an arugment to the current function that pass the caller function name)?

I don't want to dramatically slow down the execution of the program. So gdb is not an option?

dladdr may be useful for shared library. I'd like something for statically compiled executable as well.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html

EDIT:

Things like this are not helpful. If want to get the caller function name for each callee, it will require editing for each function, which is not a scalable solution.

[How can we know the caller function's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100090/how-can-we-know-the-caller-functions-name)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we know the caller function's name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100090/how-can-we-know-the-caller-functions-name)

Comment: Edited. Please remove the close vote.

Comment: `I don't want to dramatically slow down the execution of the program.` and `without adding an argument to the current function that pass the caller function name` makes this pretty much impossible.

Comment: There is no portable way to do this in C without adding arguments or similar. But notice that question also has some answers describing non-portable ways to do it on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I don't think they answer my question. But there are many answers, I may miss some. If you think a particular answer can answer my question in a non-portable way, could please point it specifically?